# How to connect Microsoft SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database

i am trying to connect mssql database using sqlsrv_connect() php function but it's always show below fatal error.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().

Code:

```
$server = 'xx.xxx.xxx.Xxx\sqlexpress';
$username = 'uname';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'testdb';


$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to download the associated driver.

**The Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Driver for PHP allows PHP developers to access data in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 databases. The driver includes support for Windows and SQL Server Authentication methods, transactions, parameter binding, streaming, metadata access, connection pooling, and error handling.**

Check these links:

[How to connect to MSSQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx)

[Php Help Documnetation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Comment: hiii thank u... for reply... i am using ubuntu and xampp server and in ubuntu .so file use as a driver. and i don't no in which folder i have place the .so driver file.